# Insert the keys 2 4 5 1 3 6 in that order into a heap. Draw the result

Tags: heap

I am working with heaps and I am unsure if this is the right category to post this question in, but the question is:

**Insert the keys 2 4 5 1 3 6 in that order into a heap. Draw the result.**

I have draw the heap  (I have attached the image), but I am unsure, if I have drawn it correctly according to the question.

[Drawn heap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22fAc.png)

Comment: An essoteric Q. Is this homework?

Comment: No. I am preparing my self for the exams. :)

Comment: Good luck to you! Don't do too much caffiene.. and you will do well.

Comment: min heap or max heap? Your figure shows a max heap.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your image is correct. Let's build the heap as items are entered.

When you insert 2, it becomes the root. Adding 4 will make 4 the root and 2 has to go to the left subtree in order to satisfy the shape property. So you have in your array, `[4, 2]`.

Now you add 5 to the end of the array and bubble it up. That results in `[5, 4, 2]`. Adding 1 gives you `[5, 4, 2, 1]`. That tree representation is:

```
        5
    /       \
   4         2
  /
 1
```

Now, when you add 3 you get `[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]`. The parent of 3 is 4, so there's no need to bubble it up, and you get:

```
        5
     /     \
    4       2
   / \
  1   3
```

Finally, you add 6 to the array and get `[5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6]`. You need to bubble 6 up. The parent of 6 is 2, so on the first pass of bubbling it up you get `[5, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2]`, and bubbling up again gives you `[6, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2]`. The tree representation is:

```
        6
     /     \
    4       5
   / \     /
  1   3   2
```